# $I-M$ is an non-invertible matrix

Tags: stochastic-processes, determinant, inverse, stochastic-matrices

Why if $M = (m_{ij})$, with dimension $n \times n$, is a stochastic matrix, then the matrix $I-M$ must be non-invertible? I think if we echelon $I-M$, then eventually we will get a zero line (i.e. $\det(I-M)=0$), but I am not sure how I can prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each column of your matrix sums to one so we have
$$(I-M)^T\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1\end{bmatrix} = (I-M^T)\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1\end{bmatrix} - M^T\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 - \sum_{j=1}^n m_{j1} \\ 1 - \sum_{j=1}^n m_{j2} \\ \vdots \\ 1 - \sum_{j=1}^n m_{jn}\end{bmatrix} = 0$$
so the kernel of $(I-M)^T$ is nontrivial, which implies that $(I-M)^T$ is singular. Now of course $I-M$ is singular as well.

Comment: I have not seen the eigenvalue and eigenvector so far. Can you use a more standard way of to prove what is in the question?

Comment: @David See the edit.

Comment: Can you modify your question in keeping in mind that $\sum_{i=1}^n m_{ij} = 1$? According to my definition of a stochastic matrix,  $\sum_{j=1}^n m_{ij} = 1$ is not true.

Comment: @David Here it is, I simply used the matrix transpose to switch rows to columns.